# props.location is undefined with route component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

i'm trying to run snippet code as below:

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="App">
          <Navbar></Navbar>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Home></Home>} />
            <Route path="/about" element={<About></About>} />
            <Route path="/contact" element={<Contact></Contact>} />
            <Route path="/challenges/*" element={<Challenges></Challenges>} />
            <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
          </Routes>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
let a = 0;

const Challenges = (props) => {
  console.log(++a);
  console.log(window.location.pathname);
  const path = props.location.pathname;
  const slug = path.split("/").slice(path.split("/").length - 1)[0];
  const challenge = challenges.find((challenge) => challenge.slug === slug);
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>30 Days Of React Challenge</h1>
      <ul>
        {challenges.map(({ name, slug }) => (
          <li key={name}>
            <NavLink to={`/challenges/${slug}`}>{name}</NavLink>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
      <Routes>
        <Route
          exact
          path="/challenges"
          element={<h1>Choose any of the challenges</h1>}
        />

        <Route path={path} element={<Challenge challenge={challenge} />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
};
```

i want to get the path at Challenges route component but it throw an error:
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pathname')
i try to log variable "a" and "window.location" to test and it log two times like this:

```
1
/challenges
2
/challenges
```

My question is why i can't take value of props.location.pathname and why its run two times and the second time it throw an error why not at fisrt time.
Thank for helping me! Hope you have a good day.

Comment: Components re-render for a variety of reasons: their props, context, or state changed, or their parent(s) re-rendered. If you wrap your `Challenges` component with `React.memo` you can prevent it from re-rendering unless its props or state change, but you often shouldn't need to worry about that. I would also expect `challenges.find` to be failing, since you don't have `challenges` defined anywhere (in the code shown at least)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issue(s)

1. react-router-dom v6 `Route` components rendered via the `element` prop don't receive [route props](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-props).
2. Route children components ***must*** use react hooks to access the route context, i.e. `useParams`, `useLocation`, `useNavigate`, etc... and therefore must be function components.
3. The `console.log` calls are in the function body so these are unintentional side-effects. This is likely why they are called twice, assuming the app is being rendered into a `React.StrictMode` component.

## Solution

`Challenges`  should use the `uselocation` hook to access the pathname. Move the console logs into an `useEffect` hook so they are called once per render ***to the DOM***.

```
const Challenges = (props) => {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(++a);
    console.log(pathname);
  });

  const path = pathname;
  const slug = path.split("/").slice(path.split("/").length - 1)[0];
  const challenge = challenges.find((challenge) => challenge.slug === slug);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>30 Days Of React Challenge</h1>
      <ul>
        {challenges.map(({ name, slug }) => (
          <li key={name}>
            <NavLink to={`/challenges/${slug}`}>{name}</NavLink>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
      <Routes>
        <Route
          path="/challenges"
          element={<h1>Choose any of the challenges</h1>}
        />

        <Route path={path} element={<Challenge challenge={challenge} />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
};
```

[v6 api-reference](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/dev/docs/api-reference.md)